# Soldered RAM in macbook air 2015

Tags: hardware, memory

This question is just to fulfil my curiosity about how my mac works.

I have a macbook air (2015) with 8GB of **soldered** RAM.
And for what I know 2 RAM modules of 4GB are faster than 1 module of 8GB because they work in parallel and each has it's own bus, but as it is soldered there are no modules, so, are they more like 2x4GB, 1x8GB, 4x2GB, ...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's *a subjective question where there is no actual problem to be solved* as described in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help) as what [types of questions to avoid asking](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Allan Just because there's no actual *problem* doesn't make a question off-topic. It's a perfectly valid and objective question looking for a technical answer about the inner workings of a MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the images at [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Mid+2012+Teardown/9457), you can see that the RAM, soldered directly onto the MBA logic board (4GB of RAM in orange outline,) is not soldered onto a RAM carrier as you would find in a computer with removable RAM. I have no absolute proof, without diving into arcane documentation, but I'm sure Apple has designed the RAM to be interleaved if that is the technology they are using.

[image]